# Using bridge pattern in java GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing my assignment on design pattern. The question is, there is a list of item in a shop. So we asked to draw the list into two ways, one for the customer view and second for the executive view. So i choose bridge pattern since it separates abstraction from implementation.

```
public interface DrawingAPI {
    public void draw(List<Item> items);
}
```

implementation interface

```
public class CustomerView implements DrawingAPI{

    @Override
    public void draw(List<Item> items) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

concrete implementor, that display list of item for the customer.

```
public abstract class UserData {
    DrawingAPI drawingAPI;

    public UserData(DrawingAPI dapi) {
        this.drawingAPI = dapi;
    }

    public void setDrawingAPI(DrawingAPI dapi) {
        this.drawingAPI = dapi;
    }

    public abstract void draw();
}
```

abstraction

```
public class TanaUserData extends UserData{
    List<Item> stockCard;

    public TanaUserData(List<Item> stock ,DrawingAPI dapi) {
        super(dapi);
        this.stockCard = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        this.drawingAPI.draw(stockCard);
    } 
}
```

a class that holds a records of items, assuming that there is a number of items in stockCard.

Here is the problem, I want CustomerView and ExecutiveView class to display the items in a Swing Table, how can i accomplish that? I can print in the console but how about in GUI?

Answer (score 0):

A Swing `JTable` uses a Swing `TableModel` to manage its data. You can either do a one time dump of your data into a `DefaultTableModel` (technically you can keep this in sync, but keeping a single source of truth is a much better design approach) or a custom `TableModel` that proxies onto the application specific collection.

You can change the superficial view using a `TableCellRenderer`. However, renderers are best when they are as thin as possible - the simplest possible translation layer. If I understand your situation correctly, you are better off with a custom `TableModel` for each view.

A custom `TableModel` may well use another `TableModel` (perhaps `DefaultTableModel`) instance to hold that actual data.

(As always don't subclass unless you have to. Ignoring this rule is depressingly common in GUI code.)